# Chromatic number of a hypercube

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, coloring, bipartite-graphs

What is the chromatic number $\chi(Q_4)$ of a four-dimensional cube. I know that all Hypercubes $Q_d$ are bipartite, so then this would yield $\chi(Q_4) = 2$, because every bipartite graph has chromatic number $2$. Am I right, because the question then looks too simple? And this applies also for $Q_3$?

If not, then it would be $4$, because it is 4-regular graph. But that more or less applies for the chromatic index.

Comment: You are right. For $Q_3$ you should be able to draw the two-coloring. For $Q_4$ too - start with a rhombic dodecahedron and fill in some internal edges and vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right: All hypercube graphs are bipartite, and "bipartite" means *exactly* "has chromatic number $\le 2$".